# access BOOL value and set table cell from an array

Tags: ios, json, uitableview, nsarray

I have a sectioned UITableView that is populated with data from my database. The data is in JSON format and then separated into three MutableArrays by what shift a person works.

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:nil];
ridersInVan = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
first = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
second = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
third = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for (int i=0; i< [json count]; i++)
{
    item = json[i];

    if ([@"1"  isEqual: item[@"watch"]] )
    {
        [first addObject:item];
    } else if ([@"2"  isEqual: item[@"watch"]] )
    {
        [second addObject:item];
    } else if ([@"3"  isEqual: item[@"watch"]] )
    {
        [third addObject:item];
    }
}
    ridersInVan = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:first, second, third, nil];
```

I have created the tableview and populated everything, but what I am trying to do is set the text color based of some values that are inside the array

```
{
        driver = 0;
        expiration = "2013-10-08";
        greenCard = 1;
        id = 5;
        name = "greg smith";
        paid = 1;
        phoneNumber = "123 345-1234";
        showNumber = 1;
        watch = 3;
    }
```

Driver, paid, shownumber are all BOOL's how can i set the textcolor by using the bool value i have this up

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:       (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.textLabel.text = [[[ridersInVan objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"name"];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [[[ridersInVan objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"phoneNumber"];

if (paid == NO && currentDate <= 8)
{
    cell.textLabel.textColor = START;

} else if (paid == YES) {
    cell.textLabel.textColor = PAID;

    isPaid = YES;

} else if (paid == NO && currentDate > 8 && currentDate <= 15)
{
    cell.textLabel.textColor = LATE;

    isLate = YES;

} else if (paid == NO && currentDate > 15 && currentDate <= 28)
{
    cell.textLabel.textColor = AFTER_VAN_DATE;

    afterDate = YES;
} else if (paid == NO && currentDate > 28)
{
    cell.textLabel.textColor = OFF_OF_VAN;
    offOfVan = YES;
}

return cell;
```

}

im trying to set the value of paid to the paid value in the array.. Any ideas?

Comment: You've added quite a bit of code but I still don't understand your data model or what your problem actually is. I suggest you trim the question down to just the salient points - I have this data, how can I get this bit - this is what I have but it gets XX instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to store an native data type in a array like int, double, bool, you should use: `[array addObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:bool]];`

And then, recover like object and use the value like this: `[[arr objectAtIndex:i] boolValue]`

Answer (score 0):

You say these values are stored in an array, but what you show is a dictionary.  Only objects can be inside an NSArray or NSDictionary.  Boolean values are typically stored as NSNumbers (since NSJSONSerialization stores all objects as NSString, NSNumber, NSArray, NSDictionary, or NSNull).

You'll need to do something like this:

```
NSNumber *paidNumber = [myDictionary objectForKey:@"paid"];
BOOL paid = [paidNumber boolValue];
```

Digging into arrays and dictionaries will get old pretty fast.  You should probably make new classes to manage this data, which would allow you to do something like:

```
Car *car = [Cars carAtIndexPath:indexPath];
if (car.paid) {
    // paid…
} else {
    // not paid…
}
```

That's covered in a [nice tutorial here](http://rypress.com/tutorials/objective-c/properties.html).

Comment: That was my original way of doing it. I made a class and everything worked great. My only issue was when I attempted to section the table I was not able to populate the sections by the watch keyword?

Comment: You can section the table however you want.  That's a topic for another question though.  You might want to take a look at TLIndexPathTools, which can help you dramatically simplify your table data modeling: https://github.com/wtmoose/TLIndexPathTools